# Why MongoDB doesn't allow to connect with the database specified?

Tags: mongodb

I installed MongoDB 4.4 on Ubuntu 20.04. Then, I created a user:

```
$ mongo
use admin
db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"foo",roles:[{role:"userAdminAnyDatabase",db:"admin"}]})
```

Then, I configured `security.authorization: enabled` in `/etc/mongod.conf` and restarted it. Now I can connect like this:

```
$ mongo localhost:27017 -u admin -p foo
```

Works just fine. However, when I'm trying to connect and specify the database `test` to use, it fails with "Authentication failed":

```
$ mongo localhost:27017/test -u admin -p foo
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All authentication information is at admin -database.

When you use authentication and need to login to a different DB than the default, you need to tell mongo what is the authentication DB. This is done with parameter `--authenticationDatabase admin`.

So, in your case:

```
mongo localhost:27017/test -u admin -p foo --authenticationDatabase admin
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by running:

```
$ mongo
use test
db.createUser({user:"admin",pwd:"foo",roles:[{role:"dbOwner",db:"test"}]})
```

I still don't understand the logic...